# Sort nested lists by list

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

How can I efficiently sort nested lists by the first element of each nested list matching the order given in order list?

List of lists: `[[97, 2, 0, 2], [97, 2, 0, 2], [98, 1, 2, 3], [99, 3, 3, 6], [99, 3, 3, 6], [99, 3, 3, 6], [101, 1, 6, 7], [100, 1, 7, 8]]`

Order list: `[97, 98, 99, 99, 101, 100, 97, 99]`

Desired list: `[[97, 2, 0, 2], [98, 1, 2, 3], [99, 3, 3, 6], [99, 3, 3, 6], [101, 1, 6, 7], [100, 1, 7, 8], [97, 2, 0, 2], [99, 3, 3, 6]]`

Comment: What if there are two sublists which are not equal, but start with the same number?

Comment: In my case nested lists are identical if their first element values are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `dict` keyed to the first value from your nested list. Then build the output list from that `dict`:

```
nl = [[97, 2, 0, 2], [97, 2, 0, 2], [98, 1, 2, 3], [99, 3, 3, 6], [99, 3, 3, 6],
      [99, 3, 3, 6], [101, 1, 6, 7], [100, 1, 7, 8]]

# Associate first value in list to the list
d = {v[0]: v for v in nl}

order_lst = [97, 98, 99, 99, 101, 100, 97, 99]

# Grab the list associated to each value in order_list from d
out = [d[v] for v in order_lst]
print(out)
```

`out`:

```
[[97, 2, 0, 2], [98, 1, 2, 3], [99, 3, 3, 6], [99, 3, 3, 6], [101, 1, 6, 7], 
[100, 1, 7, 8], [97, 2, 0, 2], [99, 3, 3, 6]]
```

---

*Note this assumes that all sub-lists in the nested list are acceptable values as multiple variants of the same key are not supported in a `dict`.

Comment: You might want to add `nl.sort()` in case the nested list is not sorted by the first number beforehand.

Comment: `nl` doesn't need to be sorted by the first value for this to work. Order doesn't matter in creating the `dict` and the new order is specified in `order_lst`.

Comment: Yeah, this method doesn't need a sort.